# How to change one column of data to multiple column based on row using Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I dont know if I put the question correctly..
For example, I want

```
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

change into

```
1  0  1  
0  1  0
1  0  x
```

The first list should not be changed..
and change the type to DataFrame..

I try use numpy.array, flatten the array. and reshape to columns using reshape(-1,3).T ..
but since there are some missing value to it.. I cannot reshape the array properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to add the missing values to the array before resizing.

Starting point:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# I assume you flattened the array.
data = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ])
```

Adding the new data based on the required shape and fill value:

```
new_shape = (3, 3)
fill_value = np.NaN

missing_length = np.product(new_shape) - data.size
missing_array = np.full(missing_length, fill_value)

data = np.hstack([data, missing_array])
```

Then apply the reshape and convert it to a dataframe:

```
data = data.reshape(new_shape)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output:

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  0.0  NaN
```